# Pandas aggregation on timedelta and its behaviour

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, timeserieschart

I am struggling to do aggregation on timedelta including plotting. The raw data is available here
Essentially the data has a submit (datetime) , resolved (datetime) , PauseTime (timedelta) and Resolved-Submit-Pause ( which is the actual time to resolve )

[click here for data](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/arun-siv/fda5314ddc2a44bb99cfccd69909f3ab/raw/ce116e90cbca6bce6f3822edce96874a324c735d/timeseries.csv)

```
test_df = pd.read_csv('test_df.csv')

#convert to date time stamps
test_df[['Submit','Resolved']] = test_df[['Submit','Resolved']].apply(pd.to_datetime)

#CONVERT PauseTime and Resolved-Submit-Pausetime to Timedelta

test_df['PauseTime']=pd.to_timedelta(test_df['PauseTime'])
test_df['Resolved-Submit-Pausetime'] = pd.to_timedelta(test_df['Resolved-Submit-Pausetime'])
```

I am trying to aggregate mean for each day of 'Resolved'

```
test_df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='Resolved', freq='D')])['Resolved-Submit-Pausetime'].mean()
```

which gives me an error - 'DataError: No numeric types to aggregate'

1) How can I aggregate  on mean .

2) Also some guidance for plotting trend of the mean time to resolve (x axis will have all the dates and y axis agg mean timedelta of 'Resolved-Submit-Pausetime')

Comment: I am able to get test_df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='Resolved', freq='D')])['Resolved-Submit-Pausetime'].describe()  work  and my pandas version is '0.20.3'

Answer (score 1):

Use this step to convert your time delta column into seconds:

```
test_df['Resolved-Submit-Pausetime'] = test_df['Resolved-Submit-Pausetime'].astype('timedelta64[s]')

0      1234.0
1     27380.0
2     33017.0
3      5454.0
4       433.0
5      2302.0
6     21753.0
7      3405.0
8      4779.0
9      3974.0
10     3389.0
11      114.0
Name: Resolved-Submit-Pausetime, dtype: float64
```

Then run your groupby statement to compute the mean:

```
test_df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='Resolved', freq='D')])['Resolved-Submit-Pausetime'].mean()

Resolved
2017-04-01    20543.666667
2017-04-02     7485.500000
2017-04-03     3132.200000
Name: Resolved-Submit-Pausetime, dtype: float64
```

You can use Pandas built in plotting tools to do a quick and dirty plot of mean time with respect to the groupby day:

```
test_df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='Resolved', freq='D')])['Resolved-Submit-Pausetime'].mean().plot()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help. How can we make the axis in hh:mm format?